# How do I use impersonation within a Vue.JS app

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, impersonation, vue-props

I am working on an app with Vue.JS frontend, where a user logs in and is sent to a list of other users. Also on this page, there is another tab for a list of hospitals (once clicked, it will take you to a new page with list of hospitals).

One of the methods the logged in user can do when on the user page is to select one of the users to impersonate. Once they have confirmed they want to impersonate this user, the user page refreshes to show a grid of the list of users the impersonated user has access to see. While impersonating, they should also be able to go between tabs (users to hospitals), continuing the impersonation, so now the list of hospitals will render a list of the hospitals the impersonated user has access to see. In order to confirm that a user is being impersonated, there should be a textbox on the page showing that "{User} is now impersonated."

I am able to do part 1, impersonating user on the user page, but once I click the hospitals, the data that is stored as 'isUserImpersonated' refreshes (once impersonation is created, then isUserImpersonated switches from false to true. When I refresh a page, isUserImpersonated will switch back to false). How can I keep the data to stay the same for each page, instead of refreshing once a new path is rendered (localhost:8080/users -> localhost:8080/hospitals?

I am trying to use EventBus after reviewing documentation, which seems to work, but the data won't remain the same once you render a new page.

Has anyone used impersonation in a Vue.JS project? Do you have any tips or ideas on what I can do to make sure 'isUserImpersonated' remains the same if a user switched between pages?

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason that this is not working is because the change you made is stored in memory, which is erased when you navigate to a new page.

In order to make this work, you need to use some sort of persistent storage. You have a couple of options:

1. **Store & load the impersonated user data with a cookie**

   using [vue-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookie)

   ```
   this.$cookie.set('impersonation', { ... store whatever data you need }, 1);
   ```

   Check if you are impersonating a user when the page loads:

   ```
   mounted() {
     this.impersonation = this.$cookie.get('impersonation');
   }
   ```
2. **Store the impersonated user data on the server**

   This implementation depends entirely on your server stack. Most frameworks offer a session or cache that you could leverage.

Comment: thank you that's very helpful. With this process, in my method of impersonating a user, I am calling an API with a response including "impersonated_as", which becomes the impersonated user's email. Can I use this stored information somehow?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like that is what you would want to store. See in my answer where I said `{ ... store whatever data you need}`. You could substitute the email address you receive from the server here.

Answer (score 0):

3. **Use Vuex for state management**
   I'm expanding a bit on Vince's answer above.
   First off, yes I have used impersonation in a Vue app successfully. As your app scales, which is likely given that you are working with hospitals (not sure if this is for a school project or real-world stuff), you will be accessing and mutating state from multiple locations.  Vuex gives you the ability to separate state from the view, and allows mutation through actions.  I would strongly suggest at least looking into it.